# TextFormField Validation Not Working Correctly

Tags: flutter, validation

I am new to Flutter development, and I'm currently working on the sign in screen for my first full application. I apologize if this has already been asked, but I cannot figure out where my code is going wrong. I'm attempting to test basic form validation, just checking whether anything has been written into the form fields before I continue.

The code for my form is as follows:

```
class SignInForm extends StatefulWidget {
  const SignInForm({super.key});

  @override
  SignInFormState createState() {
    return SignInFormState();
  }
}

class SignInFormState extends State<SignInForm> {
  final _signInFormKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[

          TextFormField(
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              border: OutlineInputBorder(),
              hintText: 'Username',
            ),
            validator: (String? value) {
              if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                return 'Please enter a valid username';
              }
              return null;
            },
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
            child: TextFormField(
              obscureText: true,
              enableSuggestions: false,
              autocorrect: false,
              decoration: const InputDecoration(
                border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                hintText: 'Password',
              ),
              validator: (String? value) {
                if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                  return 'Please enter a valid password';
                }
                return null;
              },
            ),
          ),  

          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [
                TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xFF0b2240)),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_signInFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('Log In'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
              children: [      
                TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                    foregroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Color(0xFF0b2240)),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    if (_signInFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                      ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
                        const SnackBar(content: Text('Processing Data')),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                  child: const Text('+ Sign Up'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),    
    );
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help improving my code!

Answer (score 1):

Your forgot the key for the form widget, that's why validation don't work.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Form(
      key: _signInFormKey,
      child: Column(
...
```

More infos here : https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation